# Cannot change directory with "cd" command when it is executed inside cell in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am running a Python notebook inside a Google Cloud Platform Virtual Machine.

I was trying to change directory by running this code inside a cell in a Jupyter notebook.

```
print(user_path)
```

> `/home/praveen`

```
!pwd
!cd '{user_path}'
!pwd
```

> `/home/jupyter`
>
> `/home/jupyter`

As seen above, the path is the same after the `cd` command is executed. Is this a restriction in Jupyter?

Comment: If each of those lines is executed in its own shell, only the one would change directory.

Comment: @Shawn the two pwd commands and cd command are executed in the same cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behavior for Jupyter. All `!` commands are executed in their own subshell, so the result is not permanent. You can do what you're after in a more durable way by prefixing with a `%` instead:

```
In [0] : !pwd
/Users/z4
In [1] : %cd ..
/Users
In [2] : %pwd
'/Users'
In [3] : !pwd
/Users
```

I would not try and rely on this for anything but interactive sessions, as a convenience. If you need a shell script, write a shell script. To use `%` you need "automagic" enabled (which it should be by default).

You can also get around this to some extent by just making all of the shell commands execute in the same shell:

```
In [0] : !pwd && cd .. && pwd
/Users/z4
/Users
In [1] : !pwd
/Users/z4
```

In this case Jupyter is passing everything after the `!` to the shell, and it is the shell that is interpreting the `&&` in the usual way. This is a hack (so is the first solution) so please be wary of the resulting behavior.